# selecting a range of cell from a specifc character until a specific character

Tags: excel, selection, vba

I'm using VBA for Excel (Macro) and I have a series of data that I need to re-arrange. My objective is that I need to select a a range of cell from every ! until the next ! and paste it on a different sheet. Each selection will be pasted on its own column. Here's a sample of my data:

!
 
vpdn-group LNS_LEGACY_INFOCOM
 
 accept-dialin
 
  protocol l2tp
 
  virtual-template 2
 
 terminate-from hostname DSL_INFOCOM_L2TP
 
 lcp renegotiation on-mismatch
 
 l2tp tunnel password 7 1543595F507F7D73706A65
 
!
 
vpdn-group MGISWUP
 
 accept-dialin
 
  protocol l2tp
 
  virtual-template 3291
 
 terminate-from hostname MGISWUP
 
 lcp renegotiation on-mismatch
 
 l2tp tunnel password 7 10590C0B0A161F
 
!
 
vpdn-group PRULIFE
 
 accept-dialin
 
  protocol l2tp
 
  virtual-template 1024
 
 terminate-from hostname prulifeuk
 
 lcp renegotiation on-mismatch
 
 l2tp tunnel password 7 120E00051D0A01

**take note: 1 selection is**

vpdn-group LNS_LEGACY_INFOCOM
 
 accept-dialin
 
  protocol l2tp
 
  virtual-template 2
 
 terminate-from hostname DSL_INFOCOM_L2TP
 
 lcp renegotiation on-mismatch
 
 l2tp tunnel password 7 1543595F507F7D73706A65

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you have any try or code, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for your rows to check them, and a variable for storing row number of start point then by using `Range` in VBA you can `Copy` it anywhere you want!

You need to know the number of the last row of your column for your loop; something like this:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie here, could you give an example assuming the last cell on the data above corresponds as the last row of my column? Also, how can I select based on criteria which is text should be after and before "!"? I'm sorry. :(

Comment: I thought you have a column (A => 1) and in it each of your line stores in a cell, Am I right?

Comment: Yes, let's say the data on my column A is the data above. :)